# Ball trajectory exactly the same after reset (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am currently having trouble making a pong game. Normally, you would expect the trajectories of the pong ball to vary randomly after each Reset() is called, but somehow it is stuck in the previous trajectory and will continue along that path.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float rand;
    Vector3 ballinitialpos;
    Vector3 lastpos;
    Vector3 lastVect;
    Vector3 newVect;
    Vector2 directionVector;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        ballinitialpos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        Nudge();
    }


    void Nudge()
    {
        rand = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2);
        if (rand <= 1)
        {
            directionVector = new Vector3(-20f,10f,0f);
        }
        else
        {
            directionVector = new Vector3(20f,10f,0f);

        }
         rb.velocity = directionVector;
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        lastVect = rb.velocity;
  
    } 

    void Reset()
    {
        transform.position = ballinitialpos;
        
        Nudge();
    }

  
   
    void ReflectVector(Vector3 vect, Collision2D collision) {
        ContactPoint2D cp = collision.contacts[0];
        newVect = Vector3.Reflect(vect.normalized,cp.normal);
        rb.velocity = newVect * 20f;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)

    {
        
        lastpos = transform.position;
        ReflectVector (lastVect,col);
                
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("hitboxP1") || col.gameObject.CompareTag("hitboxP2"))
        {
            Reset();
            
        }     
      
    }
```

Explaining stuff is not exactly my strong suit. So, if my question is confusing, please do tell me so and I will try to reformat the question to the best of my abilities, based on what you think is confusing. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Random.Range` has 2 definitions: one using floats and one using ints. The one using floats generates a random floating point number (i.e. with decimals) anywhere between the minimum and maximum. The one using ints generates a random integer (i.e. a whole number), but the maximum is also **exclusive**, meaning that it will generate a number between the minimum and **one less** than the maximum.

For example, `Random.Range(0, 10)` would generate a number between 0 and 9.

In your `Nudge` function you write `rand = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2);`. Since you are using 2 integers as arguments, it will be using the integer definition of `Random.Range`. Therefore the number will be an integer between 0 and 1. Since those are both less than or equal to 1, the if statement will always set `DirectionVector` to the same thing.

To fix this you could replace it with the float definition of `Random.Range` by using floats as arguments. I.e. `rand = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 2f);`. Now it will generate a number anywhere between 0 and 2, and it will be less than or equal to 1 half the time.

For more details, see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html.